# HashWithIndifferentAccess in related models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, mass-assignment

I've got a rails app where I'm linking fields across two databases. The database stuff all seems to be fine.

However, I have one form where I am mapping a description from the remote database to a product in the local database.

The form the used to create the product and select the description works fine

```
#_form.rb
 semantic_form_for @products do |f| 

   f.input :name
   semantic_fields_for :description_maps do |description|
     description.input :desciption_map_id, :input_html=>{:name=>"product[description_map][description_id]}, :collection => @descriptions
   end
 end

#product.rb 
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :description_map_attributes, :description_map

  has_one :description_map

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :description_map
```

when I submit the form, I get an error

```
DescriptionMap(#...) expected, got ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess(#othernumber)
```

I can't seem to figure out why this is happening.

the parameters being posted look fine

```
"product"=>{"name"=>"test name", 
"description_map"=>{"description_id"=>"1"}}
```

Comment: your are not using correctly the nested model. Did you try to do f.fields_for :description_maps ?

Comment: I'm using formtastic, so it is semantic_fields_for, that is correct.

Comment: Well ok... And f.semantic_field_for or something like that? You have to nest your form...

Answer (score 1):

turns out this was an issue with how formtastic was naming the description map. 
In the question, i had specified

```
 description.input :desciption_map_id, :input_html=>{:name=>"product[description_map][description_id]}, :collection => @descriptions
```

but the 'description_map' needed to be 'description_map_attributes' like this

```
 description.input :desciption_map_id, :input_html=>{:name=>"product[description_map_attributes][description_id]}, :collection => @descriptions
```

Hopefully this answer helps somebody else having the same issue.

Comment: Golden! I'm on rails 3.0.x, not using formtastic. I'm using checkboxes in an array of nested forms. I have to "build" the form myself using check_box_tag instead form_helper/fields_for.check_box because rails does not handle the checkbox array nicely. Was floundering until, ding!, add '_attributes' in the nested attr name. Found so many complicated answers around this question when the correct answer, in my case anyway, is so simple (and make sense once it clicks). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use: :description_map (without "S") cause is a has_on relation

```
semantic_fields_for :description_map do |description|
  description.input :desciption_map_id, :input_html=>{:name=>"product[description_map]      [description_id]}, :collection => @descriptions
```

end